# In a modern SPFx Web Part, how do I check if a URL exists?

Tags: web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript

I am creating a Web Part that shows a video that might or might not be in another Document Library.

If the video exist, I should display it.

If it doesn’t, I should display another video.

How can I create a _videoExixts function in typescript?

In javascript I would do something like this:

```
function _videoExixts(url)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status!=404;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if list item already exist when adding it with](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257233/how-to-check-if-list-item-already-exist-when-adding-it-with)

Comment: yeah it is a great approach . Thanks!